# Hello, Rails! No route matches [GET] "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Decided to try learning RoR. Got stuck in the very beginning of the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

Did everything exactly like in tutorial (except `del public/index.html` instead of `rm public/index.html`, since I have a windows) Checking localhost and getting:

> No route matches [GET] "/"

Comment: Have a look at the step immediately after where you delete `index.html`.

Answer (score 4):

Your site needs a root of some sort.  If some index file does not exist in public/ (index.html|htm, default.html|htm, etc)  then you need to tell your rails app where to go.

You can do this by editing your routes.rb (found in your config/ folder) and adding the line

```
root :to => 'somecontroller#index"
```

`somecontroller` represents the controller to use, and `index` represents the method that it should handle.  typically index is preferred, which will render `index.html.erb`

You can find out more about routes by typing

```
rake routes
```

in your console.

Answer (score 1):

you should add:

```
 root :to => 'home#index'
```

see section 4.2 of the tutorial

The `root` route is the default route for your Rails application.
You can point this to any controller and action you wish to display as the "main page".

```
root :to => "controller#action"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont set a root path after you delete index.html?

maybe put your route

```
root :to => 'post#index'
```